# IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe, when reloading page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a small javascript function which sends a signal to my flask app to recalculate some figures using ajax. If the figures are produced correctly I would like to reload the page with the new figures. Since the figures are cached, I am adding a version number to the figure filename (using '?'), which should enforce the reload.
My code looks like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/process_figures",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({}, null, '\t'),
    success: function(data){ 
        if(data.error){
            console.log('Error = ', data.error)
        }
        else{
            var images = document.getElementsByClassName('metric_img');
            for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
                images[i].src = images[i].src.split("?")[0] + '?version=' + new Date().valueOf();
            }
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

However, this code always results in

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2017 14:59:39] "GET metrics_indices_1.png?version=1511189978191 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, 
in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 196, 
in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 164, 
in write
    self.send_header(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 412, in send_header
self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong here? Also, I don't really need to reload the page. If somebody knows how to use javascript to reload only the images, that would be great as well

Answer (score 0):

Ok changing the javascript code to

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('metric_img');
for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    var image_src = images[i].getAttribute('src');
    if(image_src){
        image_src = image_src.split('?')[0] + '?version=' + new Date().valueOf();
        images[i].setAttribute('src', image_src);
    }
}
```

works fine... not sure why, but its much better, since it does not require a page reload.